# Selenium WebDriver - getthe first row of a table in C#

Tags: c#, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

I'm a total selenium newbie, so the code below is far from perfect(supported by the fact that it doesn't work). I want to get the first row in a table and check whether it has a certain CSS class assigned to it.

I've been unsuccessful so far after multiple attempts to just get the 1st row. Here's what I've tried -

***The reason I'm using (RemoteWebElement) cast here is because the (IWebElement) cast isn't working. This doesn't work though.***

```
IWebElement first_row = (RemoteWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor) Driver).ExecuteScript("return $('#headTable > tr:visible:first')");
```

***The below line gets the text of all visible rows. This works.***

```
IWebElement first_row = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#headTable"));
```

***Another attempt to get the 1st row. This doesn't work***

```
IWebElement first_row = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#headTable")).FindElement(By.CssSelector("tr:visible:first"));
```

I've been looking at Examples from http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example .. But they are pretty simple examples.

Can anyone see what's wrong here?

Also, if you have links to other sites that have helpful examples in C#, I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WebDriver, but does it make use of jQuery's selector engine if it finds jQuery in use? The native browser selector engine doesn't support `:visible` or `:first` because those aren't CSS selectors.

Comment: I'm not aware of the jQuery selector engine. Could you point me to a reference page/examples please?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors - the script that you're using `$('#headTable > tr:visible:first')` is a jQuery call with a selector that is specific to jQuery only, and is not part of CSS. As I understand, WebDriver piggybacks onto the browser's native CSS selector engine, but I'm not sure if there's a way to hook a different engine to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, BoltClock is right, you're using jquery selector into a cssSelector.

```
WebElement table = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#headTable")); // you have the table
list<WebElement> allElements = table.findElements(By.CssSelector("tr[attribute name='visible']")); // you have all row that are visible
```

and finally if you want to get a row, do `allElements.get(0)`

**Important :**

Take a look at `By.CssSelector("tr[attribute name ='visible']")` because i just wrote `[attribute name='visible']` because i don't know how it's write into your code so you can adapt.

PS : there's some specs about [cssSelector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Any time you're working with HTML tables in WebDriver you should consider using the TableDriver extension (https://github.com/jkindwall/TableDriver.NET).  For the specified problem of seeing if the first row in a table has a particular CSS class, you could do it like this:

```
Table table = Table.Create(driver.FindElement(By.Id("headTable")));
TableRow row = table.FindRow(0);
string rowClasses = row.Element.GetAttribute("class");
Assert.IsTrue(rowClasses.Contains("expected-class"));
```